# sql SELECT query - which merges 2 identical tables?

Tags: sql

So I have 2 tables. `Employee` and `Draft_Employee`. They are identical, except that properties in `Draft_Employee` allow nulls.

The reason for the 2 identical tables, is that the draft_Employee is a table used for an import procedure - it is a tempoary container. We don't want the data messed up with the production employees.

Now, when a employee has to be imported, the system has to check if the employee already exists in the database.

First it see's if it can find an employee in Employee table with the same EmpID.
If found, it will look at employee in Draft_Employee and find the properties which are NULL or EMPTY. It will then take the value for the same field in Employee table and put it into the empty or NULL fields in draft_Employee

```
empID   name   something1   something2   |   empID    name    something1   something2
-----   ----   ----------   ----------   |   ----     ----    ----------   -----------
1       Casper  blahblah    blahblah2    |   2        Michael NULL         text2fs
2       Michael txttxt                   |
```

Right is Employee and left is Draft_Employee.

I want an sql query that produces

```
empID   name     something1   something2
-----   ----     ----------   ----------
2       Michael  txttxt       text2fs
```

The closest I have come, is with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but it gives me data from both tables

EDIT: My query. I did not use it before, because the spelling is danish.

```
SELECT * FROM Kladde_Ressource
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ressource
ON Ressource.RessourceID = Kladde_Ressource.RessourceID
WHERE Kladde_Ressource.EAN = ''
OR Kladde_Ressource.navnLang = ''
OR Kladde_Ressource.navnKort = ''
etc...
```

Comment: Could you please show the query you used?

Comment: If the Emplyee table doesn't allow nulls, why is there a null in the example data?

Comment: Nice catch! I just wrote a quick simplefied version of my table and made a mistake. Correcting it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't entirely grasp your requirement so I am basing my query on the data and required result you've posted.

As to get the results merged into one result set

- use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to get the first non-NULL value from both tables.
- use an [INNER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa217023%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to remove the non-matching rows.

**Statement**

```
SELECT  e.empID
        , COALESCE(e.name, de.name) AS name
        , COALESCE(e.something1, de.something1) AS something1
        , COALESCE(e.something2, de.something2) AS something2
FROM    employee e
        INNER JOIN draft_employee de ON de.empID = e.empID
```

Comment: That is awesome. I did not know that function/method. How do i retrieve the result, so it just looks like I am selecting/returning a draft_employee? I am using it as a stored procedure, so it would be nice to just get an Draft_Employee object (C#) returned

Comment: @CasperT, you can name the columns. I have altered my answer to reflect that.

Comment: We have a winner. Thanks a lot. You have made my morning

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT Employee.empId, 
       ISNULL(Employee.name, Draft_Employee.name) AS name, 
       ISNULL(Employee.something1, Draft_Employee.something1) AS something1, 
       ISNULL(Employee.something2, Draft_Employee.something2) AS something2
FROM   Employee LEFT OUTER JOIN
       Draft_Employee ON Employee.empID = Draft_Employee.EmpId
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `coalesce` function to get the first non-null value:

```
select
  e.empID,
  coalesce(d.name, e.name),
  coalesce(d.something1, e.something1),
  coalesce(d.something2, e.something2)
from
  Employee e
  inner join Draft_Employee d on d.empID = e.empID
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `UNION` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT empID, name, MAX(something1) AS something1, MAX(something2) AS something2
FROM (
    SELECT empID, name, something1, something2 FROM Employee WHERE empID = 2
    UNION
    SELECT empID, name, something1, something2 FROM draft_Employee WHERE empID = 2
)
GROUP BY empID, name
```